# Store integers in a 2d array from a text file

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am working on a project, I am given a txt file which contains x and y coordinates of a city. Here is the sample of the txt file.

> 401  841
>
> 3082 1644
>
> 7608 4458
>
> 7573 3716
>
> 7265 1268
>
> 6898 1885
>
> 1112 2049
>
> 5468 2606
>
> 5989 2873
>
> 4706 2674
>
> 4612 2035
>
> 6347 2683
>
> 6107  669
>
> 7611 5184
>
> 7462 3590
>
> 7732 4723

The numbers on the left are x coordinates and the numbers on the right are the y coordinates. I am trying to store the numbers in a 2d array [i][j] where i contains the x coordinate and j contains the y coordinates. Here is the code for storing the elements so far

```
public static void readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File Coordinate_File = new File("C:\\Users\\hasan\\Downloads\\Bahcesehir University\\Year 3\\Semester 2\\Formal Languages and Automa Theory\\Project\\att48_xy.txt");
    Scanner ScanFile = new Scanner(Coordinate_File);
    int ctr = 0; 
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    float[][] Coordinates; 
    x = ScanFile.nextInt();
    y = ScanFile.nextInt(); 
    Coordinates = new float[x][y]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            Coordinates[i][j] = ScanFile.nextInt();
            System.out.println(Coordinates[i][j]);

        }
    }


}
```

However, I am having trouble with it. The code is skipping the first line of the txt file and then after a few iterations it doesn't stop when it reaches the end of the txt file.

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are reading the first line as x and y, before entering the for loops. Does the first line in the txt file contain the number of items to read?

Comment: @Klarth No, it contains the x and y coordinates like the other lines. I think I get it now. The first line is setting the size of the array? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to do it. One of them is below:

```
        try {
            int[][] num = Files.lines(Paths.get("...File_Path"))
                    .map(s -> {
                        String[] s1 = s.split(" ");
                        return new int[]{Integer.parseInt(s1[0]), Integer.parseInt(s1[1])};
                    })
                    .toArray(int[][]::new);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           .../Handler
        }
```